# Как использовать нейросеть для распознания элементов чертежа?

Tags: нейронные-сети, распознавание-символов, распознавание-образов

Необходимо распознать элементы чертежа из pdf документа. Каждый графический элемент необходимо сопоставить с его названием и ST кодом, который бы соответствовал ему в модели. Подскажите, в таком случае придется писать собственную нейросеть по типу персептрона или же можно воспользоваться какими-то готовыми решениями, заточенными под подобные задачи?

Comment: pdf  векторный или скан? что такое ST  код?